# No Split lines in the HTML Table Column Header, why?

Tags: html, css, header, border

I am using WordPress for my site.

I set the CSS for elements including table, tr, td so that it will shows the cell lines. However, the final result shows that  all other cell lines are OK, except for the column headers. The column headers are merged into one section without any splitter. Why?

The CSS rules to add borders are:

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Just fixed the issue based on the answer, and make it more concise:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table th, td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table th:first-child, td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr:last-child th, td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 2.5em 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-color: inherit;
}

tr {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Access Repair 4.1</td>
      <td>daccr.exe</td>
      <td>9.52MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/access-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/daccr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Excel Repair 3.9</td>
      <td>dexcelr.exe</td>
      <td>8.57MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/excel-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexcelr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Word Repair 4.5</td>
      <td>dwordr.exe</td>
      <td>8.81MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/word-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dwordr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen PowerPoint Recovery 2.2</td>
      <td>dpptr.exe</td>
      <td>8.63MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/powerpoint-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dpptr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Repair 8.8</td>
      <td>dolkr.exe</td>
      <td>12.5MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dolkr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Express Repair 2.5</td>
      <td>doer.exe</td>
      <td>6.18MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-express-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/doer.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Express Undelete 2.2</td>
      <td>doeu.exe</td>
      <td>1.66MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-express-undelete-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/doeu.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Express Drive Recovery 1.0</td>
      <td>doedr.exe</td>
      <td>1.27MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-express-drive-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/doedr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Exchange Recovery 8.8</td>
      <td>dexr.exe</td>
      <td>12.3MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/exchange-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Drive Recovery 8.8</td>
      <td>dodr.exe</td>
      <td>11.2MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-drive-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dodr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Password Recovery 1.2</td>
      <td>dopr.exe</td>
      <td>6.51MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/outlook-password-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dopr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen BKF Repair 3.6</td>
      <td>dbkfr.exe</td>
      <td>7.84MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/bkf-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dbkfr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Zip Repair 3.7</td>
      <td>dzipr.exe</td>
      <td>8.03MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/zip-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dzipr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen TAR Repair 3.0</td>
      <td>dtar.exe</td>
      <td>7.61MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/tar-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dtar.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen CAB Repair 2.4</td>
      <td>dcabr.exe</td>
      <td>6.44MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/cab-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dcabr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen RAR Repair 3.7</td>
      <td>drar.exe</td>
      <td>7.89MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/rar-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/drar.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen SQL Recovery 6.3</td>
      <td>dsr.exe</td>
      <td>8.09MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dsr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen DBF Repair 3.1</td>
      <td>ddbfr.exe</td>
      <td>7.78MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/dbf-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/ddbfr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Oracle Recovery 1.0</td>
      <td>dorcr.exe</td>
      <td>1.49MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/oracle-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dorcr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen PDF Repair 3.2</td>
      <td>dpdfr.exe</td>
      <td>8.46MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/pdf-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dpdfr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen DWG Recovery 3.2</td>
      <td>ddwgr.exe</td>
      <td>60.7MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/dwg-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/ddwgr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen PSD Repair 3.1</td>
      <td>dpsdr.exe</td>
      <td>7.97MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/psd-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dpsdr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Data Recovery 2.4</td>
      <td>ddr.exe</td>
      <td>11.2MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/data-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/ddr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen NTFS Undelete 2.0</td>
      <td>dntu.exe</td>
      <td>1.46MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/ntfs-undelete-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dntu.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Office Repair 5.7</td>
      <td>dofr.exe</td>
      <td>27.8MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/office-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dofr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Database Recovery 2.7</td>
      <td>ddbr.exe</td>
      <td>11MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/database-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/ddbr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Archive Repair 3.8</td>
      <td>darcr.exe</td>
      <td>16.3MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/archive-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/darcr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Disk Image 2.2</td>
      <td>ddki.exe</td>
      <td>5.79MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/disk-image-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/ddki.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Backup 1.7</td>
      <td>dbkup.exe</td>
      <td>6.54MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/backup-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dbkup.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen File Splitter 1.2</td>
      <td>dfsp.exe</td>
      <td>5.12MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
<use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
</svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/file-splitter-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dfsp.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is because they are `<th>`s and not `<td>`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed:

```
    table th {
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 2.5em 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #eee;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}

tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Access Repair 4.1</td>
      <td>daccr.exe</td>
      <td>9.52MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
          <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
        </svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/access-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/daccr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Excel Repair 3.9</td>
      <td>dexcelr.exe</td>
      <td>8.57MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
          <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
        </svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/excel-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dexcelr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Word Repair 4.5</td>
      <td>dwordr.exe</td>
      <td>8.81MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
          <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
        </svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/word-repair-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dwordr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen PowerPoint Recovery 2.2</td>
      <td>dpptr.exe</td>
      <td>8.63MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
          <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons/icons.svg#cloud-download-alt"></use>
        </svg><a download-link="https://www.datanumen.com/powerpoint-recovery-download-thanks" href="https://download.datanumen.com/downloads/file/dpptr.exe" class="download-url"> Download</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DataNumen Outlook Repair 8.8</td>
      <td>dolkr.exe</td>
      <td>12.5MB</td>
      <td>
        <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-20">
          <use href="https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/icons
```